# how to check modification history of a file in unix

Tags: unix, unix-timestamp

In my unix environment I want to check get the list of modifications (timestamp,user etc..) done to a file.

Can someone tell me the command to get that information (I tried FIND, STAT command)

Comment: Unless you're recording it using the accounting subsystem, there's no way to get this information as it's not recorded.

Comment: Not all file systems record this information; are you sure the one you are using does?

Comment: I'm not sure If UNIX has this by default....or atleast Can I get list of files that were modified between specific dates regardless of their current modification dates @Petesh

Answer (score 2):

If the change has occurred in the past, and you are trying to look backward to find it, and file system auditing has not been set up on your system, you are **definitively out of luck**.

You may be able to use `stat(2)` to find the most recent modification time, but no other information will be available

Linux contains an `audit` subsystem which you can install and activate if you need to do this for future changes to files.